# Visual studio - Autocompletion pop-ups don't preselect items

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with Resharper (from JetBrains), and I have a little issue with the autocompletion pop-up.

In Resharper options, I set all the Autopopup behavior on "Display and preselect"

[image]

But sometimes the autocompletion does not preselect the item, like this :
[image]

(here I need to press 'Down' then 'enter' and not only 'Enter' ).

Here it works correctly (I just need to press 'Enter') :

[image]

It is annoying because I have the habit of JebBrains IDEs, with which the autocompletion always preselects items, so I use to instant press 'Enter' regardless if the item is preselected or not.

Someone have the same problem or a solution ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think the first example is the VisualStudio autocomplete. Look at the formatting difference between the two.

There may be an option to totally disable the VisualStudio autocomplete. I don't know for sure as I've never looked.